# Create hierarchy of user types

Tags: php, oop

I need to create of hierarchy of user types with these values :

- "anonymous"
- "user"
- "user-confirmed"

So I want that depending of the user type, he is also considered to have the previous roles like this :

- anonymous -> anonymous
- user -> user, anonymous
- user-confirmed -> user-confirmed, user, anonymous

The goal is that if I call a method on all users with the type anonymous, I want the method to also be called to user and user-confirmed.

What is the best way to implement this hierarchy in php ?

Comment: You should do a bit more research. However what you have here seems to be more about user permissions then types.

Comment: "What is the best way" mostly a primary opinion question.

Comment: Anyway, you could create groups and add user into other group on each step. Every group has its own set of permissions, result permissions is merge of all groups.